# Given a transition table do digraph, determine if it is DFA or NFA and build grammar

Tags: discrete-mathematics, automata, regular-language

**For the next transition table:**

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline&0&1&2\\\hline a&a&b&d\\\hline b&a&b&c\\\hline c&c&d&a\\\hline d&c&c&a\\\hline\end{array}\\a\text{ is initial state}\\\{a,d\}\text{ are final states}$$

1. **Make the digraph of the finite automaton and indicate if it is DFA (deterministic) or NDFA (non-deterministic).**
2. **Build a regular grammar that generates the language recognized by the automaton and indicate it.**

---

1. The digraph I made is:

[image: Digraph]

where $\mathrm{start}=a$, $\,s0=b$, $\,s1=c$, $\,s2=d$ and the states marked with a tick are final states.

The finite state machine (which is an automaton) $A=(\{a,b,c,d\},\{0,1,2\},\delta,a,\{a,d\})$, where $\delta:\{a,b,c,d\}\times\{0,1,2\}\to\{a,b,c,d\}$ is deterministic because each state has at most one change of state for each letter of the alphabet and there are no state changes for the null word.

2. A regular $\require{cancel}\cancel{\text{grammar}}\text{ expression}$ could be: $$\require{cancel}\xcancel{\begin{align*}L(A)&=0^*\\&\vee2^*\\&\vee(220^*2^*)^*\\&\vee(11^*0)^*\\&\vee(11^*20^*\vee2)^*\\&\vee(11^*20^*\vee(12))^*\\&\vee(11^*20^*\vee1)^*.\end{align*}}$$ \begin{align*}a&=0^*\vee1b\vee2d\vee\lambda\\b&=1^*\vee0a\vee2c\\c&=1d\vee2a\vee0^*\\d&=1c\vee0c\vee2a\vee\lambda\end{align*} and from here I do not know how to build the regular expression and then build the regular grammar (I have seen [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/68575) and [this](http://vasy.inria.fr/people/Gordon.Pace/Research/Software/Relic/Transformations/RE/toRG.html) links but I do not understand them since I could not even get the regular expression) because I have never seen an automaton with $2$ final states!!

Also, **the statement what does it mean by *indicating* the regular grammar?**

Everything is correct?

Thanks!

**External link:**

1. Automaton created by [automatonsimulator.com](http://automatonsimulator.com/). You can test it introducing words [here](http://automatonsimulator.com/#%7B%22type%22%3A%22DFA%22%2C%22dfa%22%3A%7B%22transitions%22%3A%7B%22start%22%3A%7B%220%22%3A%22start%22%2C%221%22%3A%22s0%22%2C%222%22%3A%22s2%22%7D%2C%22s0%22%3A%7B%220%22%3A%22start%22%2C%221%22%3A%22s0%22%2C%222%22%3A%22s1%22%7D%2C%22s1%22%3A%7B%220%22%3A%22s1%22%2C%221%22%3A%22s2%22%2C%222%22%3A%22start%22%7D%2C%22s2%22%3A%7B%220%22%3A%22s1%22%2C%221%22%3A%22s1%22%2C%222%22%3A%22start%22%7D%7D%2C%22startState%22%3A%22start%22%2C%22acceptStates%22%3A%5B%22start%22%2C%22s2%22%5D%7D%2C%22states%22%3A%7B%22start%22%3A%7B%22isAccept%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22s0%22%3A%7B%22top%22%3A150.66666412353516%2C%22left%22%3A316%7D%2C%22s2%22%3A%7B%22isAccept%22%3Atrue%2C%22top%22%3A276.66666412353516%2C%22left%22%3A0%7D%2C%22s1%22%3A%7B%22top%22%3A276.66666412353516%2C%22left%22%3A351%7D%7D%2C%22transitions%22%3A%5B%7B%22stateA%22%3A%22start%22%2C%22label%22%3A%220%22%2C%22stateB%22%3A%22start%22%7D%2C%7B%22stateA%22%3A%22start%22%2C%22label%22%3A%221%22%2C%22stateB%22%3A%22s0%22%7D%2C%7B%22stateA%22%3A%22start%22%2C%22label%22%3A%222%22%2C%22stateB%22%3A%22s2%22%7D%2C%7B%22stateA%22%3A%22s0%22%2C%22label%22%3A%220%22%2C%22stateB%22%3A%22start%22%7D%2C%7B%22stateA%22%3A%22s0%22%2C%22label%22%3A%221%22%2C%22stateB%22%3A%22s0%22%7D%2C%7B%22stateA%22%3A%22s0%22%2C%22label%22%3A%222%22%2C%22stateB%22%3A%22s1%22%7D%2C%7B%22stateA%22%3A%22s1%22%2C%22label%22%3A%220%22%2C%22stateB%22%3A%22s1%22%7D%2C%7B%22stateA%22%3A%22s1%22%2C%22label%22%3A%221%22%2C%22stateB%22%3A%22s2%22%7D%2C%7B%22stateA%22%3A%22s1%22%2C%22label%22%3A%222%22%2C%22stateB%22%3A%22start%22%7D%2C%7B%22stateA%22%3A%22s2%22%2C%22label%22%3A%220%22%2C%22stateB%22%3A%22s1%22%7D%2C%7B%22stateA%22%3A%22s2%22%2C%22label%22%3A%221%22%2C%22stateB%22%3A%22s1%22%7D%2C%7B%22stateA%22%3A%22s2%22%2C%22label%22%3A%222%22%2C%22stateB%22%3A%22start%22%7D%5D%2C%22bulkTests%22%3A%7B%22accept%22%3A%22%22%2C%22reject%22%3A%22%22%7D%7D).

Comment: Technically you've given a *regular expression*, not a *regular grammar*.

Comment: @Math1000 oh you are right. Do I have to create the set of productions?

Comment: I am not sure if $L(A)$ was done correctly because, for example, $12122\not\in L(A)$ `:/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of writing this, the crossed out answer in the question is a regular *expression*, but your new answer is **almost** the correct regular *grammar*! (**almost** because production rules should not have Kleene star, unlike as you wrote in $a=0^*\ ...$) Using your notation, a full specification/"indication" of the regular grammar should be the following:

- Terminal Symbols: $0,1,2$
- Non-terminal Symbols: $a,b,c,d$
- Production Rules (incomplete; please fill-in):

$$\begin{align*}a&\rightarrow0a\vee1b\vee2d\vee\lambda\\b&\rightarrow 1b\vee0a\vee2c\\c&\rightarrow\ ...\\d&\rightarrow\ ...\end{align*}$$

- Start Symbol: $a$

**Edit:** Now I see that the "*indicating it*" part of question #2 is confusing. Unless "indicating" is formally defined in your class (very unlikely), I think the better thing to do in case something like this happened in exam is to ask the examiner for clarification (e.g. "Does *indicate* mean to show the tuple?").

On my comment about "*if I were to take the exam*", treat it as "according to *my own* understanding of the question" and as *I* understand question #2, indicating the grammar just means complete specification of the 4-tuple.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Please look at [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3051700/given-a-transition-table-do-digraph-determine-if-it-is-dfa-or-nfa-and-build-gra/3055210#comment6298738_3053906). That is how they defined me to build a regular grammar from a DFA. As you can see, a grammar $G$ is a $4$-tuple. Do you think that just by mentioning the productions the section b) is solved, or on the contrary, we have to also mention the language generated by $G$ i.e. $ L(G)$ (which is probably *very* long)?

Comment: As an example, a language generated by a grammar could be $L(G)=\{0^j1^k(0^l1^m)^r,j,k,m\geq1,r\geq0\}$. Just so you know how I should write the set $L(G)$ of our case.

Comment: Oh! Now I am also confused by that *indicating it* part... But if I were to take the exam, I will not specify the explicit language as a set anymore, because the regular grammar (and actually the FSA) already represents a certain regular language.

Comment: Ok. Please let's recap: a) The digraph is the image that we already know is fine, and also the finite automaton is deterministic. b) To build a regular grammar, we have to consider the $4$-tuple $G=(\{a,b,c,d\},\{0,1,2\},P,\{a,d\})$, where $P$ is given by $$P:\begin{cases}a\to0a/1b/2d/\lambda\\b\to0a/1b/2c\\c\to2a/0c/1d\\d\to0c/1c/2a/\lambda,\end{cases}$$ and we have already indicated the regular grammar. Do you think that is the correct answer?

Comment: The start symbol should only be $a$, not $\{a,d\}$. Also, see my edit on my answer.

Comment: Oh you are right! Unfortunately I have no contacts with the teachers, so we can not know what they meant by "indicate". Finally, "build a grammar", in this context, is equivalent to giving only the productions? P.S. Sorry for being somewhat reiterative, I want to be sure that I can understand it thanks to your help.

Comment: It just instructs you to construct the grammar, and most of the work is on the production rules. So yes you can think it like that.

Answer (score 2):

Using [FSM2Regex](http://ivanzuzak.info/noam/webapps/fsm2regex/), I encoded your transition table:

```
#states
a
b
c
d
#initial
a
#accepting
a
d
#alphabet
0
1
2
#transitions
a:0>a
b:0>a
c:2>a
d:2>a
a:1>b
b:1>b
b:2>c
c:0>c
d:0>c
d:1>c
a:2>d
c:1>d
```

The resulting state transition graph:

[image]

And the generated regular expression:

```
2+2((0+1)(0+1(0+1))*(1+2+12)+2)+11*(2(0+1(0+1))*(1+2+12)+0)+(0+$+2(2+(0+1)(0+1(0+1))*(2+12))+11*(0+2(0+1(0+1))*(2+12)))(0+2(2+(0+1)(0+1(0+1))*(2+12))+11*(0+2(0+1(0+1))*(2+12)))*(2+2((0+1)(0+1(0+1))*(1+2+12)+2)+11*(2(0+1(0+1))*(1+2+12)+0)+0+$)+0+$
```

In FSM2Regex syntax, a valid regex consists of alphanumeric characters representing the set of input symbols (here 0, 1, 2), the $ character representing the empty string, the choice operator +, the Kleene operator *, and parentheses ( and ).

The state machine is deterministic. There are no ambiguous state transitions where the machine has a choice which state to assume next.

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar) for a definition of a regular grammar. Note that a grammar and a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) possibly can be converted to each other but are different concepts.

To derive a regular expression, several algorithms or visual methods exist. See [this post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/how-to-convert-finite-automata-to-regular-expressions) for a detailed explanation. Basically, internal (= non-initial and non-final) states are removed step-by-step. Result is a state transition diagram or table with only the initial and one or more final states. The transition condition from initial to a final state is the regular expression.

Comment: Thanks!! I see that we agree with the digraph (nice!). I would like to know 1) how to get to the regular expression, 2) what rules should be used to build the regular grammar, which is what the second section asks for, and 3) once done 2), what does "indicate the grammar" mean?

Comment: For your question 3), I guess "indicate the grammar" simply means to list your final answer (which is the set of production rules), after you *build* it.

Comment: I have read the section of a book that I have and it says the following: **Construction of a regular grammar from a deterministic finite automaton**. Given the deterministic finite automaton $A=(Q,V,\delta,q,F)$, to construct the regular grammar $G=(V_n,V_t,P,s)$ that generates the regular language $L(G)$ such that $L(G)=L(A)$ is produced in the following way: i) $V_n=Q$, ii) $V_t=V$, iii) $s=q$, and the productions of $P$ are given by: i) $p\to a\delta(p,a)$, ii) $p\to\lambda\text{ if }p\in F$.

Comment: I would like to know if instead of finding the regular expression and then using the regular language, you can do the productions (the transitions that you used) to then generate the grammar and thus its language. What method do you think is most confusing?

Comment: I ask because the regular expression is *very* extensive, which makes it very difficult (at least for me) to reach the regular grammar. If you prefer not to answer the message that is above this is fine. Actually this is an examination exercise, there must be some typing error because nobody could dedicate as much time to a single exercise as this in an exam...